# Python import error: No module named 'pyscopus'

Tags: python, scopus

Why am I getting an `ImportError`? 
I have an API key to access in Scopus but the code doesn't work.

```py
from pyscopus import Scopus
key = 'key'
scopus = Scopus(key)
```

Comment: Did you do `pip install pyscopus` ?

Comment: yes, it did not work

Comment: Maybe your code is using a different environment then to what you installed the package to?

Comment: Either pyscopus is not installed, or you do not have the correct permissions to access it. Do you see pyscopus in your site-packages or otherwise anywhere on your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: I'm facing this issue right now,
The following command must be run outside of the IPython shell:

    $ pip install pyscopus

The Python package manager (pip) can only be used from outside of IPython.
Please reissue the `pip` command in a separate terminal or command prompt.

See the Python documentation for more information on how to install packages: